# Обновление вложенного PreferenceScreen

Tags: android

Делаю настройки для своего приложения используя AppCompatPreferenceActivity. В классе, в onResume() PreferenceFragment, в summary каждого параметра вывожу текущее значение. При изменении значения параметра summary обновляется.

Не могу понять, как сделать вывод текущих значений в summary во вложенном PreferenceScreen.

При изменении значения параметра во вложенном PreferenceScreen summary меняется, а вывод начальных значений в summary не происходит.